# Controls not being drawn at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

I have a form which I'm bringing up using `ShowDialog` which contains a couple of text boxes, labels and a button. The problem I'm having is that the text boxes are being drawn before the form itself and the other controls are drawn.

I am overriding the `OnPaint` method I'm not sure if this could be causing the problem:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

It's only a slight delay but it's visible and annoying. Thank you.

The form is double buffered by the way.

**EDIT:** I have pinpointed the issue to be the fact that the form does not have a `FormBorderStyle`. With the `FormBorderStyle` set to `Sizable`, this issue does not occur. However please note that having `FormBorderStyle.None` as my border style is necessary, so I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Can you post all relevant code pertaining to the drawing of the Labels, Textboxes and Buttons?

Comment: Actually, the parent element calls each child control's render method before rendering itself. This is the default behavior. May be you can show the dialog once the form load is completed.

Comment: All controls have been added via the Visual Studio designer so I did not touch the drawing of these controls.

Comment: @saravanan I'm instantiating the Form globally and calling `ShowDialog` when I need to show it. When would the `Load` event be raised in this case? If I understood correctly, you are suggesting I call `ShowDialog` in the `Load` event, is this correct?

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri: can you try to draw the border in the `Shown` method as given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

Comment: How would I get a reference to the `Graphics` object from the `Shown` event?

Comment: Does this issue occur when DoubleBufferred = false?

Comment: Yes, but I have found out the problem. See my edit.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri: You can obtain a new graphics object from inside the Shown event by using this.CreateGraphics but I doubt that would solve your current problem.

Comment: Since you were able to solve your problem, can you add the solution as an answer?

Comment: I have not solved my problem, I just found the source. I updated the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the dialog box form:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            // Activate double buffering at the form level.  All child controls will be double buffered as well.

            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED

            return cp;
        }
    }
```